# Change text colour in individual list view based on variable

Tags: android, json, parsing

I followed this tutorial about parsing JSON. All is working as it should have have edited it to more my needs. I am getting information about 'servers' and one of the fields is 'status' (either UP or DOWN).

EDIT: forgot to post tutorial link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

It currently looks like this: http://puu.sh/8Ky0B.jpg
The above is what happens then the app is loaded. the on click is when a single item is clicked it starts a new activity and shows that information individually.

You can see the second server status is 'DOWN'. Based on this I want to change the text colour to RED for down and keep it green for up.

How can I do this when it goes through and adds each listview?

Here is the code which (currently) is basically the same as the tutorial:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    serverList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // Listview on item click listener
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name))
                    .getText().toString();
            String ip = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.ipAddress))
                    .getText().toString();
            String status = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.serverStatus))
                    .getText().toString();

            // Starting single server activity
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    SingleContactActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_IP, ip);
            in.putExtra(TAG_STATUS, status);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    });

    // Calling async task to get json
    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 * */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // Creating service handler class instance
        ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, ServiceHandler.GET);

        Log.d("Response: ", "> " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {
                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Servers
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                    String ip = c.getString(TAG_IP);
                    String status = c.getString(TAG_STATUS);

                    // tmp hashmap for single server
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                    contact.put(TAG_IP, ip);
                    contact.put(TAG_STATUS, status);

                    // adding server to server list
                    serverList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("ServiceHandler", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, serverList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_IP,
                        TAG_STATUS }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.ipAddress, R.id.serverStatus });

        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
```

Comment: Use custom Adapter if you want to customize list items like this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make a custom adapter and in the `getView()` you should check if the status of the server is down then set the color of corresponding textview to red else set it to green.

your getView() should like as following: (This is just a blueprint for your code)

```
getView(){
     String serverstatus = server.getStatus();
    // get status should be method in method in model class for server.
    if(serverstatus.equals("DOWN")){
       tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
       tv.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

1. Make a model class.

> ```
> class Server{
>    String serverName, serverIp, serverStatus;
>       // getter and setter.
>   }
> ```

1. Make array adapter of `Server` type.
2. In Adapter's getView() inflate the row item, and set the details. For, red color font blueprint is already added.

Comment: Im looking at this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html But do I do it on the PostExecute e.g. replace this:
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, serverList,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_NAME, TAG_IP,
                        TAG_STATUS }, new int[] { R.id.name,
                        R.id.ipAddress, R.id.serverStatus });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

Sorry, I havent used custom adapters myself.

Comment: This is useful tutorial, in section `14.2. Tutorial: Domain Model and Rows interaction`, this approach is explained.

Comment: Yes, in `onPostExecute()` you can do this work, since setting adapter works on UI thread and `onPostExecute()` also runs on UI thread. So you can set adapter in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

In the definition of list Adapter, in the getView() method, find the textview and change the text color.

```
TextView tv = (TextView) listItem.findViewById(R.id.server_status);
tv.setTextColor(android.R.color.primary_text_dark);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take the custom Adapter (a BaseAdapter) instead of simple adapter,

and there you perform your operation in getView() method.

Answer (score 0):

You've done most of the hard work already :)

First create an object to store server details rather than a HashMap (which are slow and heavy) plus an object is more adaptable and fits your purpose better.

I've created a super fast example (not complete as to your details, but should be easy to expand).

```
package com.example.adaptertest;

public class HolderServer {

String serverName;
boolean isServerUp;

public HolderServer(String serverName, boolean isServerUp) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
    this.isServerUp = isServerUp;
}

public String getServerName() {
    return serverName;
}

public void setServerName(String serverName) {
    this.serverName = serverName;
}

public boolean isServerUp() {
    return isServerUp;
}

public void setServerUp(boolean isServerUp) {
    this.isServerUp = isServerUp;
}
}
```

Next you'll need to create a custom adapter. In your example you're actually using a simple adapter (ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter() which is a great first step, but we can improve on that a little by extending it. This will allow us to change what happens to each individual element in the listview. i.e. change the color etc.

Here's a quick example:

```
package com.example.adaptertest;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdapterServers extends ArrayAdapter<HolderServer>{

ArrayList<HolderServer> mServers = new ArrayList<HolderServer>();
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
Context mContext;

public AdapterServers(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<HolderServer> servers) {
    super(context, resource, servers);
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mContext = context;
    mServers = servers;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //Inflate view for each element in list.
    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.server_list_item, null);

    //Get details for current server
    HolderServer server = mServers.get(position);

    //Set server name
    ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_list_item_txt_servername)).setText(server.getServerName());

    //Now we set the status text and color 
    TextView status = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.server_list_item_txt_serverstatus);
    if(server.isServerUp){
        status.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.up));
        status.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    }else{
        status.setText(mContext.getResources().getString(R.string.down));
        status.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
    }

    return convertView;
}
}
```

Now back in your code, first in onCreate create a new list of objects:

```
ArrayList<HolderServer> mServerList = new ArrayList<HolderServer>();
```

then instead of this:

```
                // tmp hashmap for single server
                HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<String, String>();

                contact.put(TAG_ID, id);
                contact.put(TAG_NAME, name);
                contact.put(TAG_IP, ip);
                contact.put(TAG_STATUS, status);
```

You'll create your new object & add it to the list. Obviously update it with your variables once your HolderServer object is updated:

```
    HolderServer server = new HolderServer("Server1", true);
    serverList.add(server);
```

Then apply that list to the adapter and apply the adapter to the listview:

```
    AdapterServers adapter = new AdapterServers(this, 0, serverList);
    ((ListView) findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_listview)).setAdapter(adapter);
```

Good luck!